# Git ignoring nested repos?

Tags: git

Recently I made a git repo out of directory that already contained two git repo subdirectories. Since then I've only been committing at the parent level...

Today I broke by codebase and tried to rollback. But the rollback didn't take for the sub-repos. I looked in github, and instead of directories, they had different icons: (See the bottom two)

[image]

What is going on? what are these icons? Has the parent repo been ignoring these directories? Is that default behavior with nested repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how git works. Each repository is its own repository and has its own state. You can link two repositories together by using submodules. The green arrow on a folder means that it's a link to another repository (a submodule).

You can read [more about git submodules here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). Your post as it currently stands isn't really asking a question.

Comment: The question is- Does a history exist for those directories and how do I access it?

Comment: Each git repo has its own history. The parent git repo only stores info about which commit of the submodule the parent module was synced with.

Comment: So the parent repo was not committing the subdirectory contents?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You need to commit to them separately. The parent repo only commits which commit the submodule was pointing at. If the submodule is dirty (as in, had files or changes that weren't individually commited to the submodule's separate repo), those changes aren't committed anywhere.

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for (though not the one i wanted). Thanks.

Comment: I understand. Best of luck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To get at the history / content of the inner folders, do git commands inside those folders.  Putting git folders inside each other is confusing as it doesn't merge the repositories or create any relation.  If you need them to be together, merge them together or use submodules.  If they should be separate, move them to separate folders -- purely to help keep it straight in your head.